# Web.Config de WEB API ASP.Net Web Core

Tags: asp, webapi, net

Estoy teniendo problemas al levantar mi WebApi en el IIS. Me indica un error de Web Config.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero desconozco por que . 
Alguien tendria alguna idea? Mi Web.Config es el siguiente-->

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments="TodoAPI.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false"  hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 8b209fdf-9e97-4309-8158-54530d986472-->
```

Comment: El error pareciera ser otro, puedes colocar la ruta donde publicaste la web?

Comment: Según el título de tu pregunta, estás trabajando con ASP.NET Core?. Debes saber que en ASP.NET Core no hay Web.config. Si te has equivocado, por favor edita y corrige la pregunta.

Comment: Te deja hacer ping al sitio?